# How do I query MongoDB for 2 ranges and text search?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have event objects in MonogDB that look like this:

```
{
    "start": 2010-09-04T16:54:11.216Z,
    "title":"Short descriptive title",
    "description":"Full description",
    "score":56
}
```

And I need to get a query across three parameters:

- Time window (event `start` is between two dates)
- Score threshold (`score` is > x)
- Full-text search of `title` and `description`

What's the right way to approach this efficiently? I think the first two are done with an aggregation but I'm not sure how text search would factor in.

Comment: Can you store your start field as date instead of string?

Comment: @matthPen oh, yes, that was my mistake in transcribing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `start` field is of type `date` (which it should be) and not a `string`, here are the basic components that you'd want to play with. In fact, given the ISO 8601 structure of a MongoDB date a string based comparison would work just as well.

```
// create your text index
db.collection.ensureIndex({
   description: "text",
   title: "text"
})

// optionally create an index on your other fields
db.collection.ensureIndex({
   start: 1,
   score: 1
})

x = 50
lowerDate = ISODate("2010-09-04T16:54:11.216Z") // or just the string part for string fields
upperDate = ISODate("2010-09-04T16:54:11.216Z")

// simple find to retrieve your result set
db.collection.find({
    start: {
        $gte: lowerDate, // depending on your exact scenario, you'd need to use $gt
        $lte: upperDate  // depending on your exact scenario, you'd need to use $lt
    },
    score: { $gt: x },   // depending on your exact scenario, you'd need to use $gte
    $text: { // here comes the text search
        $search: "descriptive"
    }
})
```

There is an important topic with respect to performance/indexing that needs to be understood, though, which is very well documented here: [Combine full text with other index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35260539/combine-full-text-with-other-index)

This is why I initially wrote "components of what you'd want to *play with*". So depending on the rest of your application you may want to create different indexes.