# Does order matter within a MongoDB $match block having $text search?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am performing an aggregate query that contains a match, group, project, and then a sort pipeline. I am wondering if adding the text search block within my match block first vs last makes any performance difference. I am currently going based on the Robo 3T response time metric and not noticing a difference and wanted to confirm whether my observation holds true to the facts or not.

The query looks something like this:

```
db.COLLECTION.aggregate(
{$match: {$text:{$search: 'xyz'},...}},
{$group: {...}},
{$project: {...}},
{$sort: {...}}
)
```

Comment: [The $match stage that includes a $text must be the first stage in the pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/index.html#restrictions).

Comment: I know that which is why match comes before group and project

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: I'm asking whether the contents inside the match block can be written in any order or if order does matter. For example, text search appears first and then other conditions follow vs other conditions written and then the text search follows. In the latter case, would it filter out the collection by the other conditions and then text search against the filtered list or does MongoDB optimize how the `$match` pipeline works internally regardless of the order in the query?

Comment: The answers to your questions are in the following post: [Combine full text with other index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35260539/combine-full-text-with-other-index).